Как избежать ошибок после удаления данных в связи postgresql
У меня есть таблица с пользователями



id
name




1
John


2
Scott



И есть таблица, куда заносятся их действия, например, создание сообщения.



fk_id
text




1
some text


2
any text



FOREIGN KEY (fk_id) REFERENCES users (id)

Потом пользователь решает удалиться из базы данных. Соотвественно, строка с его данными в первой таблице должна стереться, но тут происходит ошибка, так как во второй таблице fk_id является внешним ключом. Как быть в такой ситуации? Вторая таблица и её содержимое обязательно должны быть сохранены.

FK имеет опциональный класс действия по изменению основной таблицы. Так что простое ON DELETE SET NULL. Только нужно понимать, что удаление юзера не даст возможности потом понять, чья запись в логе. Так что наилучшее решение - это "мягкое удаление".

Есть два общепринятых варианта

Во второй таблице столбец fk_id делается с допустимым значением null, и сам FK создаётся как ON DELETE SET NULL. То есть запись остаётся, но без ссылки на пользователя. На многих сайтах с пользовательским контентом используется такой механизм, а вместо логин пользователя отображается что-то типа "пользователь удалён".

Запись из первой таблицы не удаляется, а помечается как удалённая. Для этого можно в таблицу добавить специальный столбец-флаг. Или же можно модифицировать сам ID так, чтоб было понятно, что запись удалена, например, для целочисленных заменить знак числа на минус. И в нужных местах в логику программы добавить проверку что пользователь ещё не удалён.



Для этого в таблицу добавляется специальный столбец-флаг. Гораздо более изящно выглядит использование знаковых синтетических ключей и изменение знака ключа при удалении (плюс ON DELETE CASCADE). Во-первых, отрицательные первичные ключи обычно в условии отбора отсеивать проще, чем использовать для этого отдельное булево поле. Во-вторых, даже простой просмотр глазом сразу показывает в общей массе, кто удалён (особенно в подчинённой таблице, не требуется JOIN с основной). Ну и партиционировать в этом случае проще, если вдруг захочется вымести из рабочей таблицы удалённые записи.

@Akina, у меня в практике специфика другая, где каскадный UPDATE сотен тысяч записей не приветствуется.

Ну я и не пытаюсь утверждать, что такой подход безальтернативно лучше. Если связанных записей реально гора - конечно, нафиг каскадные операции. Но если их от силы десяток, и уж тем более если сама база с кукиш размером - то почему бы и не да?
